# Is 'Dispose' required for a variable in a loop created with 'Activator.CreateInstance'?

Tags: c#

I am creating a dynamic variable (action) with `Activator.CreateInstance` in a loop.
Should I use `Dispose` before next loop? What is the optimal code for action variable to prevent memory leaks?

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var job = await DbHelper.FromProcAsync<JobQueue>("WJbQueue_Start1st", cancellationToken: stoppingToken);

        if (job?.JobId > 0)
        {
            dynamic action = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(job.ActionType));

            await action.ExecuteAsync(stoppingToken);

            // Do I need Dispose for action variable here?
        }

        await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you shouldn't call `Dispose()`?

Comment: just by code, we see many memory allocation, but the deallocation is not obvious ...

Comment: `(action as IDisposable)?.Dispose();`

Answer (score 1):

If the class in question implements `IDisposable`, then yes, it would be good practice to call `.Dispose()` before your last reference to it goes out of scope.

That is the whole point of that interface.

However, it's up to you to find out whether the class actually does implement the interface. Since it's dynamic, we cannot tell. And neither can you at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

all objects cant be dispose and when you add `action.Dispose()` you may encounter problems while running
so do this

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var job = await DbHelper.FromProcAsync<JobQueue>("WJbQueue_Start1st", cancellationToken: stoppingToken);

        if (job?.JobId > 0)
        {
            dynamic action = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(job.ActionType));

            await action.ExecuteAsync(stoppingToken);

            // check object is disposable 
            if ( action is IDisposable )
                action.Dispose();
        }

        await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```